# Angular Materials - Footer after md-content scroll

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

I'm currently designing an app using Angular Materials, but I have encountered a layout problem. The app is divided in half with a sticky header. The left side does not scroll, but the right side will scroll. If you are scrolling through the content on the right side and reach the end, the ENTIRE page will then scroll to display a footer.

I've tried many combinations, but can't get the desired result. Any help is appreciated

Before Scrolling:
[image: Before Scrolling]

After scrolling to the end:
[image: After scrolling to the end]

Current code:

```
<body layout="column">

<md-toolbar>
    <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools"> 
        <md-button class="md-raised">Sign In</md-button>
    </h2>  
</md-toolbar>

<div ng-controller="LandingController" layout="row">

        <!-- Left Side -->
        <div flex class="search-background" layout ="row" layout-align="center center">
            <md-input-container layout="row">
                <label>Something</label>
                <input ng-model="airport">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button>Search</md-button>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Side -->
        <md-content flex layout-padding>
            <p> Text that overflows </p>
        </md-content>
</div>

<!-- Where do I put the footer/format the layout -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app/all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You didn't really describe your desired result. Do you want a sticky footer that is always visible at the bottom of the window, or...?

Comment: I want a footer that appears after the right scroll portion is completed which then overtakes the left side which is not scrollable. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have a jsfiddle for something similar to that, hope it works for you. Feel free to update the same.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulchaturvedie/mybf7fsq/38/)

```
<body ng-app="layout" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="column">
      <md-toolbar md-whiteframe="2">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <span>Material header</span>
          <span flex></span>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div class="content-section" flex>
      Should not scroll
      </div>
    <div class="content-section" flex>
      <div class="text-center">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        This Scroll
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        This Scroll
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        This Scroll
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        This Scroll
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        This Scroll
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div layout="row" flex>
    <div layout="column">
      <md-toolbar md-whiteframe="2">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
          <span>Material footer</span>
          <span flex></span>
        </div>
      </md-toolbar>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

[ng\:cloak],
[ng-cloak],
[data-ng-cloak],
[x-ng-cloak],
.ng-cloak,
.x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}

.content-section {
  height: calc(100vh - 128px)!important;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what i'm looking for. I guess my case is very specific with the page divided into two.

Comment: Very close, however the footer should only appear AFTER the scrolling has finished. Thanks for the continued effort!